# Error in posting image through REST Api Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I am trying to post image via the REST Api using the `catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1` service, but getting error in `base64_encoded_data`. The error is "The string is not a valid base64 encoded data"

```
{
  "entry":{
    "type":"image",                                              
    "label":"Image",
    "media_type":"image",
    "disabled":false,
    "content":[
      {
        "type":"image/jpeg",
        "name":"abc.jpg",
        "base64_encoded_data":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA..."
      }
    ],
    "position":1,
    "file":"abc.jpg"
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: are u calling rest api code in php or any other lang?

Comment: I am using c# to call.

Comment: try to change name with "name":"abc.jpeg"

Comment: tried both, but still not working.